# Why am I unable add +1 to this counter?

Tags: python

I know it's probably a really dumb error, but I am trying to add +1 to the counter in the init method from calling the example.  I have noticed that the counter stays at 0, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong here.

```
class newlabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(newlabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_name='PressStart2P.ttf'
        self.markup = True
        self.counter=0
        self.words = self.text.split(' ')

    def example(self, *args):
        self.counter += 1
        words = self.text.split(' ')
        if len(self.words) >= self.counter:
            self.text = hello[self.counter]
        anim = Animation(size_hint=(1, .27), duration=1.7)
        anim.start(view)

newmessage = newlabel(text = "this is a test hello")
Clock.schedule_interval(newmessage.example, 3)
```

Comment: the counter should be updating, unless Clock is doing something odd. can you make sure its not in fact updating by doing a `print self.counter` inside your `example` function?

Comment: Are you calling `app.run()` where app is attained via `from pyglet import app` ?

Comment: I have done a print self.counter inside the example method and it prints '0' every 3 seconds.  I assume everything related to the clock is working fine since it IS printing every 3 seconds.

Comment: Your program fragment is short and gets to the point. That is good. But it would be more helpful if it were complete, so that others could run your program. Please provide a short, complete program. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.ORG

Answer (score 1):

OK problem solved.  The issue was that I had a duplicate of the line.

```
self.words = self.text.split(' ')
```

The correct one being in the **init**, and I accidentally also had it in the example method which was causing it to split the words each time example was called.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```
newmessage.example
```

to actually call the function it must be

```
Clock.schedule_interval(newmessage.example(), 3)
```